# Django - Creating a User Registration Form through a CreateView

Tags: django, django-generic-views, user-registration

I'm planning to create a user registration form through a CreateView. Is this possible?

Here is the model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    favorite_food = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In views:

```
class CreateProfile(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['user', 'favorite_food']
```

However, the user field only shows a dropdown box of the users. How do you make it ask for the username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using the `django.contrib.auth` `User` model…

If you want a username and password field, you should make a `ModelForm` of the `User` model.

Here are the docs that describe how `ModelForm` works:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/